# Continuous tkinter text update in loop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, while-loop

I have created a script which constantly screenshots and finds elements on the screen, and I want to use tkinter or a similar framework to overlay text on the screen. The main script runs in a while loop and checks every x seconds, and I want the tkinter window to also update ever x seconds until the script is closed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import keyboard

def superimpose_text(text):
    color = "black" if isinstance(text, str) else 'green' if text < 10 else 'yellow' if text < 15 else 'red'
    label = tk.Label(root, text=text, font=('Times New Roman', '50'), fg=color, bg='white')
    label.lift()
    root.geometry("+1400+600")
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
    root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
    label.pack()

    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=lambda event: root.destroy())
    listener.start()

while True:
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = screenshot_info()
    superimpose_text(text)
    root.mainloop()
```

Currently I'm using a listener to destroy the label at any keypress, as that's the only way I can get It to ever update the text, but this isn't working. How do i make it continuously update every time the while loop runs?

Comment: text = screenshot_info()
NameError: name 'screenshot_info' is not defined

Comment: `while` loops and tkinter tend not to mix well, particularly if there's any slow-running or blocking process inside the loop. This can lead to slow or stuck UI. You should look into tkinter's `after()` method. I'll link a suitable answer here in a minute...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yeah the screenshot_info isnt important for the question, replace "hello world"

Comment: @JRiggles i did look into the .after method, but I cant quite figure out how to set it up

Comment: @Tobias Christensen. It worked for me.  `text = "screenshot_info()"`. But is freezing can't move window.

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes it adds text, but if you click any buttons it breaks

Comment: I pressed keyboar and disappeared. Is that it?

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes its supposed to write it again forever, that's what the while loop is for, and then the screenshot_info is supposed to give me new text each click

Comment: @JRiggles. label = tk.Label(root, text=text, font=('Times New Roman', '50'), fg=color, bg='white')
NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Comment: @toyotaSupra that's because OP declared root in a weird place

Comment: Read @Tobias Christensen's comment.

Comment: We don't offer a code writing service or trying to replace the official documentation here. Please show a minimum of effort and ask for a specific programming issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the declaration of `root = tk.Tk()` and `root.mainloop()` out of the `while` loop - tkinter runs its own GUI event loop anyway, so it's handled for you. Then, wrap the calls to `text = screenshot_info()` and `superimpose_text(text)` into a function (ex. `def update_text()`) that calls itself again using `after()`, e.g. `after(100, update_text)`. To start the updates, just call `update_text()` as normal.

```
import tkinter as tk


# instantiate Tk and set the window properties here
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("+1400+600")
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")

label = tk.Label(
    root, 
    text='', 
    font=('Times New Roman', '50'),
    fg='black', 
    bg='white',
)
label.pack()


def superimpose_text(text):
    color = "black" if isinstance(text, str) else 'green' if text < 10 else 'yellow' if text < 15 else 'red'
    # update the label
    label.config(text=text, fg=color)


def update_text():
    text = screenshot_info()
    superimpose_text(text)
    root.after(100, update_text)  # have this func call itself again every 100mS


update_text()  # start the update loop
root.mainloop()
```

There are some issues with how you're setting `color`, but I'm going to leave that to you.

Comment: The code still stops after i press a button, it doesn't continue to run

Comment: It doesn't work, man

Comment: You're calling `root.destroy()` on keyboard presses - what did you expect to happen?

Comment: line 14, in <lambda>
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=lambda event: root.destroy())
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Also, setting `root` properties like `geometry` shouldn't be handled inside a function like that if you don't actually need to set/update them more than once. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: And another important point regarding the keybinding: tkinter has built-in functionality for this, e.g.: `root.bind('<Key>' , lambda _event: callback_function())`, which is to say you probably don't need `pynput`

Comment: So I read through your question again and it sounds to me like you don't need the keypress event at all if it was just a workaround for getting the text to update. I'm going to remove that code from this answer.

Comment: Yeah the keypress was just a means to make it "work", and the solution you have made is close, but it doesn't overwrite the current text, it makes a new text block, can it be made to overwrite the old text?

Comment: Should be fixed now. The idea is to create the `Label` once, and then update it as needed

Comment: Thank you, this is so good! The one issue with it is that the tkinter window is visible for this version, it wasn't in my original version, but I cannot even see why its different. Thanks though, will marked as solved

Comment: You may need to set the color of your `root` window to match your `-transparentcolor`, i.e. `'white'`

Comment: That does remove the background of the tkinter window but not the border of the window with the topbar

Comment: i added "label.master.overrideredirect(True)" which works!

Comment: You can just use `root.overrideredirect(True)` since `root` is the `master` of your `label`